# Find highest price parallel times

Tags: sql

We have a program for afternoon classes. Each household gets a discount for attending a second class on parallel months. The cheaper class gets a discount.
e.g. we have a

- class 200 months 1-3
- class 180 months 1-8
- class 150 months 1-7
- class 120 months 1-11

I'll get discount lines:

- classD 180 1-3
- classD 150 1-7
- classD 120 1-8

[image]

my problem is with cancellation.

the functionality is simple: find same price or lower price descending in classD going through the months.

first example cancel:
   **class 200 1-3** & **class 120 1-11**

I except cancellation & cancellation discount lines :
           class 200 1-3
           classD 180 1-3
           class 120 1-11
           classD 120 1-8

second example cancel: **class 180 1-8** & **class 120 1-11**

I except cancellation & cancellation discount lines :
           class 180 1-8
           classD 180 1-3
           classD 150 4-7
           classD 120 8
           class 120 1-11
           classD 120 1-7

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_cancel_class') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #tmp_cancel_class
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_classDiscount') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_classDiscount
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_Combined') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #temp_Combined

CREATE TABLE #tmp_cancel_class
(
priceperunit money,
new_start_date datetime,
new_end_date datetime
)
INSERT INTO #tmp_cancel_class
VALUES ( 200, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-28'),
        --( 180, '2020-01-01', '2020-07-31'),
        --( 150, '2020-01-01', '2020-04-30'),
        ( 120, '2020-01-01', '2020-10-31')

CREATE TABLE #tmp_classDiscount
(
priceperunit money,
new_start_date datetime,
new_end_date datetime
)
INSERT INTO #tmp_classDiscount
VALUES ( 180, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-28'),
        ( 150, '2020-01-01', '2020-04-30'),
        ( 120, '2020-01-01', '2020-7-31')

                select * , 1 as basePoint into #temp_Combined from #tmp_cancel_class
                union 
                select * , 0 as basePoint from #tmp_classDiscount order by priceperunit desc

;with cte ( priceperunit ,new_start_date , new_end_date, basePoint)--, hierarchy, base_new_end_date, max_new_end_date_in_hierarchy) 
                as (
                select  priceperunit, new_start_date , new_end_date, #temp_Combined.basePoint --, new_end_date ,new_start_date , new_end_date
                from #temp_Combined 

                ), ordered ( ppu ,new_start_date , new_end_date, basePoint, hierarchy, base_new_end_date, max_new_end_date_in_hierarchy, last_new_end_date) as
                (select  priceperunit, new_start_date , new_end_date, basePoint , 0 ,new_end_date , new_start_date, new_start_date
                from cte where basePoint = 1 
                union all
                select  o.ppu,  o.new_start_date , o.new_end_date, o.basePoint , hierarchy + 1 ,base_new_end_date , 
                iif(max_new_end_date_in_hierarchy >= o.new_end_date , max_new_end_date_in_hierarchy, iif(o.new_end_date > base_new_end_date, base_new_end_date, o.new_end_date))
                ,o.new_end_date
                from ordered o --inner join cte  c on o.ppu < = c.priceperunit
                where o.ppu <= ppu and o.new_end_date <> max_new_end_date_in_hierarchy and  o.basePoint = 0 
                )
                select distinct * from ordered order by basePoint desc, hierarchy
```

actual result:
only lines from #tmp_cancel_class

I have a few problems:

- I want the results in a query and not looping.
- I can't get the anchor member to be from #tmp_cancel_class and a recursive member from #tmp_classDiscount.
- Last part is, to hold in memory / or different technique solution for  e.g. #2, that part of classD 120 was charged by class 180 and only 1-7 are left.
  I mind only the duplication of 8. two lines of 1-7 and 8 are fine, it can be combined later.

Comment: What are parallel months?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for commenting, only common months get a discount. e.g. A household that pays for two classes, one Jan-Mar & one class Apr-July won't get a discount. but if one is Jan- Mar and the second is Mar-June, only on March the household will get a discount on the lower class. If a class is canceled, I need to charge back the discount that was given.